# Where to Start on Comparison Tool Pulling from Database?

Tags: sql, database

Essentially I'm wanting to build a comparison tool, similar to the one seen on cars.com here: https://www.cars.com/research/compare/

I'm familiar with the basics of SQL, but wanted to know how to start pulling that information to say, a WordPress page, where it neatly presents that information.

Additionally, I want to give users the ability to search for products by multiple keys (ex. item number, name, etc.).

Comment: This would be regarded as a low quality question, please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @rxbert Sorry, still learning the way around, fixed title.